# I am trying to run the controller.py file after installing ryu but i am getting this errors again and again no matter what i do

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

```
abhijit@abhijit-VirtualBox:~/ryu$ ryu-manager controller.py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/abhijit/.local/bin/ryu-manager", line 5, in <module>

    from ryu.cmd.manager import main

  File "/home/abhijit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ryu/cmd/manager.py", line 33, in <module>

    from ryu.app import wsgi

  File "/home/abhijit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ryu/app/wsgi.py", line 109, in <module>

    class _AlreadyHandledResponse(Response):

  File "/home/abhijit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ryu/app/wsgi.py", line 111, in _AlreadyHandledResponse

    from eventlet.wsgi import ALREADY_HANDLED

ImportError: cannot import name 'ALREADY_HANDLED' from 'eventlet.wsgi' (/home/abhijit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/wsgi.py)
```

I activated my virtual env. Also tried to solve the errors by manually opening the directories but its not working at all